# How to make Pinterest PDK.request() for a DELETE request?

Tags: javascript, pinterest

I want to make DELETE /v1/me/following/boards// (via Pinterest JavaScript library). I understand that I shall use PDK.request() to make this request.

Requesting to please provide an example of how this DELETE request can be made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things to be sure of when making your request to unfollow a board. First is if you have the correct scope. Do you have the 'write_relationships' privilege? Also make sure the board spec is of the form //.

A valid request would look something like this.

```
PDK.login({ scope: 'write_relationships' }, function() {
    PDK.request('me/following/boards/<username>/<board_name>', 'DELETE', callback);
});
```